# Using dplyr filter() in programming

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I am writing my function and want to use dplyr's filter() function to select rows of my data frame that satisfy a condition. This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), y = rnorm(50), z = sample(1:100,50), w = sample(1:100, 50),
            p = sample(1:100,50))

new <- function(ang,brad,drau){
  df%>%filter(!!drau %in% 1:50)%>%select(ang,brad) -> A
return(A)
}

brand <- c("z","w","p")
lapply(1:3, function(i) new(ang = "x", brad = "y", drau = brand[i]))%>%bind_rows()
```

Anytime I run this function, it looks like `filter` doesn't select any rows that satisfy the condition.

How can I make this work?

**Update**

For some reason, this works when I don't use `%in%, as in;

```
new <- function(ang,brad,drau){
  df%>%filter(!!drau > 50)%>%select(ang,brad) -> A
return(A)
}

lapply(1:3, function(i) new(ang = "x", brad = "y", drau = brand[i]))%>%bind_rows()
```

However, the results are the same for every loop. Why is this so? and also why can't I use `%in%`.

Comment: Have a look at `filter_`

Comment: @HubertL, Yh I know that and also filter_ is getting phased out

Comment: where have you read this?

Comment: @HubertL in the dplyr man pages. do `?filter_` and you'll see it's deprecated.

Comment: Not really.. just a thought I had. Since these functions are deprecated versions, they are likely to be phased out soon. I don't want to use them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to do what you want (but it needs confirmation by you):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1492)

xdf <- data_frame(
  x = sample(1:100, 50),
  y = rnorm(50), 
  z = sample(1:100,50), 
  w = sample(1:100, 50),
  p = sample(1:100,50)
)

new_df <- function(ang, brad, drau) {
  drau <- sym(drau)
  filter(xdf, UQE(drau) %in% 1:50) %>% 
    select(ang, brad)
}

brand <- c("z", "w", "p")

map_df(brand, ~new_df(ang = "x", brad = "y", drau = .x))
```

Despite there being a plethora of "official" "tidyverse" examples using `df`, it's a function in the `stats` pkg and I try to avoid using it anymore.

Since you're using the tidyverse, might as well take advantage of `map_df()` from `purrr`.

Comment: I don't understand "plethora of "official" "tidyverse" examples using `df`, it's a function in the `stats` pkg". I don't see any `stats` function. I guess you meant `base::lapply`?

Comment: @dpprdan `df` returns the density of the F distribution and comes from the stats package. I agree with @hrbrmstr and I also stopped using `df` for naming

Comment: You can get away without loading `library(rlang)` if you replace `rlang::sym()` with base function `as.name()`

Comment: This answer will not work anymore as `UQE` is now deprecated. Please check my answer or the other.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with @hrbrmstr's standard evaluation solution. As suggested by @hadley [today](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/888281817849020418) here's NSE solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), 
                y = rnorm(50), 
                z = sample(1:100,50), 
                w = sample(1:100, 50),
                p = sample(1:100,50))

new <- function(ang, brad, drau){
  ang  <- enquo(ang)
  brad <- enquo(brad)
  drau <- enquo(drau)

  df %>% filter(UQ(drau) %in% 1:50) %>%
    select(UQ(ang),UQ(brad)) 
}

brand <- c("z","w","p")
brand <- rlang::syms(brand)

map_df(brand, ~new(ang = x, brad = y, drau = UQ(.x)))
```

Comment: I want to mention that `UQ` is now deprecated. Please have a look at double-moustache operator for modern day programming with dplyr. I recommend watching any recent talk by Lionel Henry.

Answer (score 1):

With `UQE` now deprecated, the accepted answer for this question will not work. This answer should work. The only change here is `!!sym()`

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

df <-data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), y = rnorm(50), z = sample(1:100,50), w = sample(1:100, 50),
                p = sample(1:100,50))

new <- function(ang,brad,drau){
  df%>%filter(!!sym(drau) %in% 1:50)%>%select(!!sym(ang), !!sym(brad)) -> A
  return(A)
}

brand <- c("z","w","p")
lapply(1:3, function(i) new(ang = "x", brad = "y", drau = brand[i]))%>%bind_rows()
```

If you want do not want to pass your function arguments as strings, use `!!enquo()` instead.

```
new <- function(ang,brad,drau){
  df%>%filter(!!enquo(drau) %in% 1:50)%>%select(!!enquo(ang), !!enquo(brad)) -> A
  return(A)
}

> head(new(ang = x, brad = y, drau = z))
    x           y
1  44  0.47702540
2  84 -1.09670409
3  59 -0.20556334
4  81 -0.46306635
5  93  1.36845485
6   8  0.37392587
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and the simple fix that worked for me was to use the ".data" pronoun within the "filter" verb, specifically in this context:

```
filter(.data[[drau]] %in% 1:50)
```

More info here: https://tinyheero.github.io/2020/03/01/use-data-env-pronouns-tidyverse.html
Also recent talks by Lionel Henry on Rstudio's youtube channel are helpful too.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), y = rnorm(50), z = sample(1:100,50), w = sample(1:100, 50),
                p = sample(1:100,50))

new <- function(ang,brad,drau){
  df%>%filter(.data[[drau]] %in% 1:50)%>%select(ang,brad) -> A
  return(A)
}

brand <- c("z","w","p")
lapply(1:3, function(i) new(ang = "x", brad = "y", drau = brand[i]))%>%bind_rows()
```

Hope someone finds some use in this.