# Input dplyr::filter() as argument to function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, nse

**Input dplyr::filter to function**

How to create a function which takes any dplyr::filter as input, and returns the number of rows satisfying the filter?

I have tried something like this, which does not work:

```
library(tidyverse)

filter_function <- function(dataset, filter_text) {
    dataset %>% filter_text %>% nrow() -> n_rows_satisfy_filter

    paste0( "Number of rows satisfying the filter: ", n_rows_satisfy_filter)
}
```

Here i try to input a filter as a string:

```
filter_function(iris, "filter( Sepal.Length > 5 & Species == 'setosa' )" )
```

Gives error:

```
Error in quote(., filter_text) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'quote' which requires 1
```

The question is similar but not a duplicate of [Using dplyr filter() in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45227816/1831980), because the current question attempts to vary the whole filter, not just the input to a static filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, another option is `parse_expr` from `rlang`

```
library(dplyr)
filter_function <- function(dataset, filter_text) {
  eval(rlang::parse_expr(filter_text)) %>% 
         nrow() %>%
         paste0( "Number of rows satisfying the filter: ", .)
}

filter_function(iris, "filter(dataset, Sepal.Length > 5 & Species == 'setosa' )" )
#[1] "Number of rows satisfying the filter: 22"
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid hardcoding the dataset into the string, and still use tidyverse? I.e something like `dataset %>% eval(parse_expr(filter_text))`, where filter_text is something like `filter( Sepal.Length > 5 & Species == 'setosa' )`?

Comment: @RasmusLarsen  It needs the environment of the dataset

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, `eval` evaluates the `expr` argument in the environment specified by `envir` and returns the computed value.

```
library(tidyverse)

filter_function <- function(dataset, filter_text) {
  n_rows_satisfy_filter <- eval(parse(text = filter_text), envir = dataset) %>% nrow()
  paste0( "Number of rows satisfying the filter: ", n_rows_satisfy_filter)
}

filter_function(iris, "filter(dataset, Sepal.Length > 5 & Species == 'setosa' )" )
```